# CSS :not selector element of another class

Tags: css, selector

I have a `<td>` without a class inside of `<tr class="alt">`

How do I select that, but not all `<td>` inside of the table without modifying the HTML markup?

Comment: Code please, we need to see your code.

Comment: there needs to be a way of differentiating that `<td>` from the others in the row
`tr.alt > td:nth-of-type(n)` could help - if it's the nth `<td>` in the row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a class specifier on the tr:

```
tr.alt > td
```

If you only want to select the first td inside each `tr.alt`, you can use:

```
tr.alt > td:nth-child(1)
```

Comment: What if there are other `<td>`'s inside that row?

Comment: This will select all elements that match the OP's criteria, i.e. a td inside a tr with class alt. If only the first is required, an additional `:nth-child` specifier can be added.

Answer (score 9):

If I understand you correctly and you want to target all `td`s that **don't have any class** defined then  you can do it like this

```css
tr.alt td:not([class]) {
    background-color:red;
    ...
}
```

See **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/xEuRQ/)**

If on other hand you need to target `td`s that **don't have specific class** (e.g. `main`) but may have other classes

```css
tr.alt td:not(.main) {
    background-color:red;
    ...
}
```

See **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/TYdC6/)**